# React-query is not working with a project bootstrapped with Vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I'm having a problem setting up my new project bootstrapped with Vite,

```
No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one
```

The project crash when I add the component `ReactQueryDevtools` to the code. I tried bootstrapping an app with `create-react-app` and it worked with exactly the same code.

src/App.jsx :

```
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "react-query/devtools";

import "./App.css";

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

function App() {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
      <h1>Root</h1>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I just tried out that code in a codesandbox with react-query 3.12.1 (latest) and it works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-yonath-mq6cz?file=/src/App.tsx

which version are you using?

Comment: I encountered the same problem and have opened an issue on react-query's Github: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/issues/1936. As a temporary solution you can use `react-query@3.12.0`.

Comment: @TkDodo Thanks for your answer. Yes, it works if you use create-react-app but if you scaffold the app with Vite https://vitejs.dev/ the same code doesn't work

Comment: We are tracking this here: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/issues/1936

Answer (score 1):

It's an open issue related to the devtools. We are tracking it here: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/issues/1936